# django - how can query by date

Tags: django, date, url, view, django-queryset

i need to query models by some `date`. dates passed to `reservation_f` by url. but return me this error:

```
[u'\u0645\u0642\u062f\u0627\u0631 \u062a\u0627\u0631\u06cc\u062e \xab2016\xbb \u062f\u0631 \u0642\u0627\u0644\u0628 \u0646\u0627\u062f\u0631\u0633\u062a\u06cc \u0648\u0627\u0631\u062f \u0634\u062f\u0647 \u0627\u0633\u062a. \u0628\u0627\u06cc\u062f \u062f\u0631 \u0642\u0627\u0644\u0628 YYYY-MM-DD \u0628\u0627\u0634\u062f.']
```

models.py:

```
class Food(models.Model):
    serve_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Serve Date", auto_now_add=False)
```

views.py:

```
def reservation_f(request, year, month, day):
    food = Food.objects.filter(serve_date__year = year, serve_date__month = month, serve_date__day = day)
    return render(request, 'food.html', {'food':food})
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^reserve/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{2})/(?P<day>[0-9]{2})/$', reservation_views.reservation_f, name='reserve')
]
```

template.html:

```
<a href="{% url 'reserve' date.serve_date|date:"Y/m/d" %}">
    {{date.serve_date }}
</a>
```

Comment: How exactly you expect the end url will look like?

Comment: @AndreyZarubin its wrong? where?

Comment: it is wrong in different places depending on what you are trying to achieve. For example it is not clear what kind of date format are you looking for in the url.

Comment: oh I see your changes. now, you should modify the {% url %} part accordingly

Comment: @AndreyZarubin yes. modify url, views and models

Comment: I think you will get different error with these changes

Comment: @AndreyZarubin yes. edit error code

Comment: you need to modify {% url %} to reflect your urlpatterns definition.

Comment: how to midify it?

Comment: {% url 'reserve' date.serve_date|date:"Y" date.serve_date|date:"m" date.serve_date|date:"d" %}

Comment: @AndreyZarubin tankx. your {% url %} is worked. but view return empty array. my view is correct?

Comment: I think `serve_date__date=year` is not really correct. Also, lookups such as __year could be disabled for sqlite for example.

Comment: @AndreyZarubin, not work. i have edited the view. but not work. im using mysql

Comment: @AndreyZarubin, I used my sql. I changed it to psql now. But I do not understand the cause of the problem

Comment: The cause of the problem is that you are doing queryset lookup in a wrong way. please, read the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-date-based/#dayarchiveview